# webserver SSI tag not working for some tags lwip

Tags: html, webserver, microcontroller, ssi, lwip

I am trying to implement web server code on LPC1768 without RTOS, using lwip stack and CGI and SSI method.

I am using SSI tag and CGI with HTTP as demonstrated in texas example, but on lpc1768 with lpcopen library. However my problem is I have defined 27 ssi tags in [3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xeeg90b0aykjzj/lwip_task.c?dl=0) and distributed it on 3 CGI or HTML page. When I make request for page with tags below index 23 it works fine, but when page is requested for SSI tags with index higher then 22, the ACK is lost (#30 and #31 in wireshark captured file) and no data is transferred from controller, below is wireshark packet capture. The controller doesn’t hang it respond to Ping(#62 and #65 in wireshark captured file)  or other page request.

Link: [wireshark captured packet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/io1e8uwjrzy14xn/lwip%20ssi%20tag%20err.pcapng?dl=0),
[TI_Sample.c](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmi1gdkq7mtr72f/lwip_task_TIex.c?dl=0),
[myver.c](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xeeg90b0aykjzj/lwip_task.c?dl=0)

**Below is defined SSI Tags code**

```
consttSSITagg_psTags[] = {
/* "Variable Name on page", pointer to variable register in code    */
//  { "ledrate",  (uint32_t *) &g_ui32LEDDelay },
{"ip1", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Server.IP[0]}, /* index = 0 */   // CGI req/ page 1
{"ip2", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Server.IP[1]}, /* index = 1 */
{"ip3", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Server.IP[2]}, /* index = 2 */
{"ip4", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Server.IP[3]}, /* index = 3 */
{"port1", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Server.Port}, /* index = 4 */
{"sat", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Server.AliveTime}, /* index = 5 */
{"gw1", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.GW[0]}, /* index = 6 */
{"gw2", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.GW[1]}, /* index = 7 */
{"gw3", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.GW[2]}, /* index = 8 */
{"gw4", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.GW[3]}, /* index = 9 */
{"nm1", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.NM[0]}, /* index = 10 */
{"nm2", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.NM[1]}, /* index = 11 */
{"nm3", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.NM[2]}, /* index = 12 */
{"nm4", (uint16_t *) &stUser.HostNetwork.NM[3]}, /* index = 13 */
{"cip1", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Client.IP[0]}, /* index = 14 */
{"cip2", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Client.IP[1]}, /* index = 15 */
{"cip3", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Client.IP[2]}, /* index = 16 */
{"cip4", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Client.IP[3]}, /* index = 17 */
{"port2", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Client.Port}, /* index = 18 */
{"cBaud", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Ser.Baud}, /* index = 19 */ // CGI req/page 2
{"cPar", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Ser.Parity}, /* index = 20 */
{"cDB", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Ser.Databits}, /* index = 21 */
{"cSB", (uint16_t *) &stUser.Ser.Stopbits}, /* index = 22 */
{"cMode", (uint16_t *) &stUser.DevConfig.Mode}, /* index = 23 */ // CGI req/page 3
{"pdelay", (uint16_t *) &stUser.DevConfig.InterPacketDelay}, /* index = 24 */
{"fformat", (uint16_t *) &stUser.DevConfig.Mode}, /* index = 25 */
{"psize", (uint16_t *) &stUser.DevConfig.PacketSize}, /* index = 26 */
};
```

I would like to know how to debug this issue or where to exactly look for problem.

I am trying to implement Texas instruments Tm4c129 example code of freeRTOS web server in lpc1768, with lwip stack and LPCopen library.

Also would like to know how to implement web server without rtos to share data between micro-controller and webpage.

Comment: Kindly inform if anything more is needed for to be explained.

Comment: Text quote (the pink text) is for quoted text.  A narrator should not quote themselves.

Comment: @agc17 it didn't let me submit, it use to give formatting error but couldn't conclude what was error, and the message couldn't help much.